# Why are my grouped Outlook tasks off by a day?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am trying to group my Outlook tasks by Due Date and they are grouping to be off by a day. Is there another field I should be using? Is this a DateTime issue where Outlook is doing some timezone calculation??

[image]

Comment: How long have you had this issue? Do I correctly assume restarting Outlook has no positive effect? Can you edit your question to indicate what version of Outlook you're running?

Comment: I do use Outlook2013 but don't use "tasks" normally.  I tried to duplicate this but couldn't.  I suspect you're correct about a timezone issue.  What time zone were the events created in? and is that the same timezone you're in now?  Did you create the events on the same machine or different from the one this is showing on now?

Comment: @Twisty I just noticed this today, but I only only tried doing this today. Correct, restarting Outlook had no effect. I originally tagged my question with Outlook 2013.

Comment: @Tyson All the tasks were created in MDT. Same time zone I'm in now. When I create a new task with 8/15 as the due date, it still falls under the 8/14 group. If I create a task with no due date, I can drag it into the 8/14 group and it inherits the 8/15 due date.

Comment: @Tyson Some of the tasks are emails that I flagged. Some are plain tasks I created. Some are SharePoint Tasks - all of which I created.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, I tried to make it happen but it didn't for me.